# Simple pojo persistence without database

Tags: java, persistence

I have a very simple web project, which need to just persistence some "users", each one just have a few fields("username", "password").

Now I persistent them into a database, but I think it's too heavy.

I wonder if there are some easy ways to persistent them without a database. It's great just need to save pojos directly.

---

**UPDATE**

To save them in a file directly(like serialization, properties file) is easy, but not easy with CRUD. That means, when I get a specified user, I have to load them, then check the username one by one. When I update or delete one, I need to load all and save all.

I hope something like [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/), but with a good licence(not GPL nor commercial). The performance is not important here.

Comment: You can use in memory HSQLDB http://hsqldb.org/

Comment: How much data is there in total?  Can you (for example) serialize a `List<...>` of customers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the built-in serialization for Java or have a look at some of the XML serializers, like [simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/).

SQLite might be a suitable alternative to a client/server type database, but use from Java is a little awkward, as some native libs are required.

Answer (score 0):

Using Properties file is another solution, http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html
But note that you're storing passwords, you might need to encrypt them